# how to write three csv file data into one csv file with one date column and three data column using python

Tags: python, pandas

I have three csv files with date one input value. I just want to merge this three csv file into one csv file with one date column and three inputs data.

```html
date                      X1
2018-06-08 09:30:00    450
2018-06-08 10:30:00    340.0
2018-06-08 11:30:00    200.5
2018-06-08 12:30:00    100.75
2018-06-08 13:30:00    80.875
2018-06-08 14:30:00    50.4375
2018-06-08 15:30:00    450.71875
2018-06-08 16:30:00    300.859375
2018-06-08 17:30:00    150.4296875
2018-06-08 18:30:00    40.21484375
2018-06-08 19:30:00    47.607421875
2018-06-08 20:30:00    23.8037109375


second csv

date                      X2
2018-06-08 09:25:00    300
2018-06-08 10:25:00    250.0
2018-06-08 11:25:00    170.0
2018-06-08 12:25:00    80.5
2018-06-08 13:25:00    65.25
2018-06-08 14:25:00    55.625
2018-06-08 15:25:00    40.8125
2018-06-08 16:25:00    20.90625
2018-06-08 17:25:00    10.953125
2018-06-08 18:25:00    8.9765625


third csv

date                     X3
2018-06-08 15:00:00    3
2018-06-08 16:00:00    2.5.0
2018-06-08 17:00:00    0.5
2018-06-08 18:00:00    0.35
2018-06-08 19:00:00    0.25
2018-06-08 20:00:00    0.15
2018-06-08 21:00:00    0.03125
2018-06-08 22:00:00    0.015625
2018-06-08 23:00:00    0.0078125
2018-06-09 00:00:00    0.00390625
```

Here is my three csv file:

what I expected is:

```html
date                     X1             X2        X3

2018-06-08 09:25:00      450           NaN        NaN
2018-06-08 09:30:00      NaN    300        NaN  
2018-06-08 10:25:00      NaN    250        NaN
2018-06-08 10:30:00      340    NaN        NaN
2018-06-08 11:25:00      NaN           170       NaN
2018-06-08 11:30:00      200.5         NaN        NaN   
2018-06-08 12:25:00      80.5          NaN        NaN       
2018-06-08 12:30:00      100.75        NaN        NaN       
2018-06-08 13:25:00      NaN           65.5       NaN       
2018-06-08 13:30:00      80.875        NaN        NaN      
2018-06-08 14:25:00      NaN           55.625     NaN      
2018-06-08 14:30:00      50.4375       NaN        NaN   
2018-06-08 15:00:00      NaN           NaN        3
```

Here I wrote a code but it didn't give me what I expected output.
my code:

```
df1= pd.read_csv('X1.csv')
df2=pd.read_csv('X2'.csv')
df3=pd.read_csv('X3'.csv')
df = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3])
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Final output after writing the code hprovide by jerzrael

```html
                     Unnamed: 0       X1      Unnamed: 0      X2           Unnamed: 0  \
date                                                                            
2018-06-08 09:25:00         NaN       NaN         0.0  500.000000         NaN   
2018-06-08 10:25:00         NaN       NaN         1.0  350.000000         NaN   
2018-06-08 11:25:00         NaN       NaN         2.0  250.000000         NaN   
2018-06-08 12:25:00         NaN       NaN         3.0  100.500000         NaN   
2018-06-08 13:25:00         NaN       NaN         4.0   50.250000         NaN   
2018-06-08 14:25:00         NaN       NaN         5.0   30.625000         NaN   
2018-06-08 15:00:00         0.0  2.000000         NaN         NaN         0.0   
2018-06-08 15:25:00         NaN       NaN         6.0    7.812500         NaN   
2018-06-08 16:00:00         1.0  1.5000000         NaN         NaN         1.0   
2018-06-08 16:25:00         NaN       NaN         7.0    3.906250         NaN   
2018-06-08 17:00:00         2.0  0.500000         NaN         NaN         2.0
```

Comment: You have to rename the columns to be the same for concat to align them properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `DatetimeIndex` and then use `concat` with `axis=1`:

```
df1=pd.read_csv('X1.csv', parse_dates=['date'], index_col=['date'])
df2=pd.read_csv('X2.csv', parse_dates=['date'], index_col=['date'])
df3=pd.read_csv('X3.csv', parse_dates=['date'], index_col=['date'])

df = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3], axis=1)
```

Comment: I have a one issue when I am applying your code. Can you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: @team - Sure, let me know

Comment: When I applied your code then came properly with date and other values, but on behalf of that ,X1,X2,X3 came another column named unnamed. Here I upload the final output , then you can get an idea what I am going to say?

Comment: @team - Unnamed  column is filled by `0,1,2...` values?

Comment: yes exactly. unnamed column filled by 0,1,2 .. values . Here I pasted the final answer

Comment: @team - So I know answer. Problem is it is old index values, solution should be `df1=pd.read_csv('X1.csv', parse_dates=['date']).set_index('date')` - Can you test it for all 3 DataFrames?

Comment: It gave me an error [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'X1.csv'

Comment: @team - hmmm, it looks like some no pandas problem, maybe some permission are set to file.

Comment: I solved that problem. But still same , it is showing same results after applying your new code. "unnamed column is showing"

Comment: @team - And `df1=pd.read_csv('X1.csv', parse_dates=['date'], Index_col=0).set_index('date')` ?

Comment: ya this is correct. Thankyou very much for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df=df1.merge(df2, how='outer').merge(df3, how='outer')
```